# About "return" in AuthController of Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2,I don't understand the  "return" in  AuthController,as follow:

**AuthController:**(out-of-the box)

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'role' => $data['role'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I can understand:

```
return view('index',compact('articles'));
```

and

```
return redirect()->action('ArticlesController@index');
```

But I can not understand  `return User::create([... ]);` above.

Is there any difference with the writing below?
rewrite:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'role' => $data['role'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    return back();
}
```

Comment: feel free to close the question if you are satisfied

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the controller you can see that the authcontroller uses a trait

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

so the `return User::create` will return the new registered user to the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` which will handle the login , thats why after you register you are automaticly logged in

and the difference  is that you are not logged in ( in the second code you shared)

thats all i think

Answer (score 2):

This create() method is not referenced anywhere in the routes directly, so it doesn't have to return a view (a response).

Most probably, it's used by another method of the same controller – that other method relies on create() to create a user, and then does redirects or renders a view.

In short, not all controller methods have to return HTTP responses. Some of the methods are 'internal' - they are helpers, to be used by other methods.

Answer (score 2):

User::create function is creating a user for you. User is a model and it returns a collection, with the user details. So in the first case your returning the user credentials. Eloquent always returns a collection. Read more [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections)

In the second case, the back() function redirects you back to your previous page. Your not sending the details of the user here. Read more [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects)